# Blank PhoneGap / Cordova Android apps

Tags: android, cordova

I've installed the Phonegap (latest; 3.0.0) via npm (version 1.2.32) on Windows 8 64bit and took the 2.9.0 JAR from the [PhoneGap GitHub](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/blob/master/lib/android/cordova-2.9.0.jar).

Running the example `HelloCordova` app or [PracticalPhoneGapExample](https://github.com/shawnwildermuth/PracticalPhoneGapExample) (just pasted into the `www` directory of the HelloCordova example), on a Nexus 4 AVD (default or hardware-accelerated Intel x86), I only see blank black and white sections;

[image: PracticalPhoneGapExample on a hardware-accelerated Nexus 4]
*PracticalPhoneGapExample on a hardware-accelerated Nexus 4*

If I click around a bit, then some segments of the screen are visible:

[image: After clicking, show sections are shown]

Any idea what the problem is?

#### Edit:

This does work on a physical device (Nexus 4).

Comment: try with command line tools you may get perfect project of phonegap version 3.0.0. and you must require 3.0.0 jar for 3.0.0 version

Comment: @AmitPrajapati where is the 3.0.0? As I linked, their GitHub only has the 2.9.0 JAR

Comment: in libs folder there is cordova-3.0.0.jar

Comment: Please you need to create project with comandline  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

Answer (score 0):

i've same problem previously. i solved by turn android:hardwareAccelerated to "false"

in AndroidManifest.xml